# JQuery Post data to MVC Action Method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

All I'm trying to do is to pass an array of strings/ints to mvc action method.
But the data always comes back as null, what am I doing wrong?

MVC Controller

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult MyAction(List<string> ids)
 {
   // do something with array
   // But it's null
      return View();
 }
```

JQuery

```
$.post("/MyController/MyAction", JSON.stringify(ids), function () { alert("woohoo"); }, "application/json");
```

Data being posted to action result

```
["156"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
... JSON.stringify({ ids : ids }), ...
```

I'm pretty sure the model binder isn't sure what the list/array is suppose to be bound too.

Consider:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(List<string> ids, List<string> blah)
{
}
```

If JSON is passed as just an array of values, which parameter to do bind too?  JSON can be much more complex than a FORMS submission so it also needs a bit more definition.

For example, the following would work for the previous consideration.

```
{
  ids : ["asdf","asdf"],
  blah : ["qwer", "qwer"]
}
```

**Update**

In order to send json properly the following ajax call would need to be made:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Home/Index",
  data: JSON.stringify( ids ),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

The last parameter in Post (you specified `application/json`) is what to expect back from the server.  By default, the a $.Post will do a Forms Encoded (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) contentType which appears to be hard coded into the shortcut method.  To set the contentType you have to use the long handed version $.ajax.

Comment: I have tried that already, still coming back as null    { "ids" : ["156"] }

Comment: Sorry you also have to specify the content type.  Updating answer.

Comment: I have that in my code already, I started parallel (VM) and everything works now. Too ba dI can't delete the question

Comment: You question is perfectly valid, even if the answer was found, anyone else trying to use $.post to send Json will also experience the same problem and hopefully find this solution.  That is why SO exists.

Comment: @ErikPhilips 1+ and congrats for 10k rep :)